# How to re-enable the behavior of closing modal on clicking outside of modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have written JQuery to disable the click outside modal.

Also this data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"  is not working in my condition.

So the JQuery that I have used is this to prevent closing of modal on clicking outside.

```
    $('#down_pay_modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       e.stopPropagation();
       return false;
   });
```

Now after the page loads I have to enable the modal behavior of closing when clicked outside of modal. Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right.

```
  $('#down_pay_modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
   return false;
```

});

But place this code at the bottom of your file just before

```
 </body>
</html>
```

Its working for me.